# Multiple Video, Same Screen

Tags: ios

Is it possible to play more than one video the same time / on the same screen with iOS?

(E.g. Picture-in-Picture mode or split screen.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Step by step and full source code on how to do this: http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/

Comment: Using Cezars' code from GitHub I was able to play two videos at the same time on the iPhone and have controls available for one of those videos.

Answer (score 1):

You can't using MPMoviePlayerController. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that clearly..

> Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and
>   present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time
>   can play its movie.

But I think you can do this with lower level AVFoundation framework..But I never tried it..See [this](http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66)

Comment: didn't try the suggested solution with the AVPlayer yet, but I guess Apple wouldn't approve it for the app store anyway.

Comment: @Beffa **I guess Apple wouldn't approve it for the app store anyway**  Oops, are you sure about it?

Comment: No not sure, but if the documentation says, that two videos are not supported, I don't want to invest a lot of time to build something, that has a good chance not to be approved.

Comment: **I don't want to invest a lot of time to build something, that has a good chance not to be approved**  cant blame you there..good luck

Answer (score 0):

To update the answers up today's SDKs, with the SDK for iOS 5 (and probably back to 4) you can use [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) to play video in an AVPlayerLayer and add a number of layers to a view.  I've confirmed that three separate WQVGA h.264 video streams can play on the same view at the same time under both iOS 4.3.5 on an iPhone 3GS and iOS 5.0 on an iPhone 4S.