# Show two videos at the same time on the same iOS screen

Tags: ios, video, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to show two different videos at the same time within my iOS app.  One video needs to be playing in the top half of the screen, and a separate video needs to be playing on the bottom half of the screen.  I don't need to have the stop/play/ffw/rew buttons enabled - just to show the videos playing.  I have some of my own buttons to stop and start playback, which should affect both videos.

I tried using two MPMoviePlayerController views, but it will only allow one to be playing at any one time.  I read that it's possible to have two playing in separate ViewControllers - if so, do I simply need to create two UIViewControllers and add them to the parent viewcontroller?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible on any multimedia framework level.

AVFoundation- (`AVPlayer`) and MediaPlayer-Framework (`MPMoviePlayerController`) both only support a single video playback at a time.

***Update***

The situation has changed. In fact, AVFoundation does permit multiple movie playbacks at a time. MediaPlayer still sticks towards the single playback at a time restriction.

Comment: Thanks Till.  I'm sure you're right, but I'll hang on for a little while to see if anyone offers a workaround before marking the answer correct.  Thanks for your speedy response.

Comment: I see only one possible way to achieve the given task; using third party decoders/players like e.g. FFMEG.

Comment: Where is this restriction documented?

Comment: From [MPMoviePlayerController specifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html): Note: Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8835919/514483

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain AVPlayer to implement controllers and interfaces for multiple instances of AVPlayerLayer. These may be added to the layer hierarchy, so it is very possible to have multiple videos on one screen at the same time.

Here is an [overview of one approach](http://iosguy.com/tag/avplayerlayer/) with accompanying [sample code](https://github.com/cezarsignori/MyVideoPlayer).